# Android Kotlin RxJava Retrofit - Json object that has lists as attributes expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, list, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I receive a Person object from an API that has a list of another object as one of it's attributes. I receive the following error in the logs: "Expexted BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $". So the JSON is not parsing the list correctly. I use Moshi for JsonParsing.

The Person JSON object: (In the real project there are multiple persons)

```
{
    "personId": 1,
    "personName": "Bert",
    "personAge": 19,
    "isFemale": "false",
    "dogs": [{
        "dogId": 1,
        "dogName": "Fred",
        "isFemale": "false"
    }, {
        "dogId": 2,
        "dogName": "Laika",
        "isFemale": "true"
    }],
    "birthDate": "2000-06-28T00:00:00"
}
```

The Dog data model class:

```
data class Dog(
  @Json(name = "dogId")
  val dogId: Int,

  @Json(name = "dogName")
  val name: String,

  @Json(name = "isFemale")
  val isFemale: Boolean,
)
```

The Person data model class:

```
data class Person (
  @Json(name = "personId")
  val personId: Int,

  @Json(name = "personName")
  val name: String,

  @Json(name = "personAge")
  val age: Int,

  @Json(name = "isFemale")
  val isFemale: Boolean,

  @Json(name = "dogs")
  val dogs: List<Dog>

  @Json(name = "birthDate")
  val birthDate: GregorianCalendar

)
```

ApiInterface: (note a list of Person because it always returns a list of one Person object)

```
@GET("persons/{personId}")
fun getPerson(@Path("personId") id: Int): Observable<List<Person>>
```

PersonRepository:

```
class PersonRepository @Inject constructor(val apiInterface: ApiInterface) {
  fun getPerson(personId: Int): Observable<Person>{
    return apiInterface.getPerson(personId)
      .doOnNext { value -> Log.d("PERSON_LOG_TAG", "onNext: value=$value") }
      .flatmap { response ->
         if(response.size == 1) {
            Observable.just(response[0])
         } else {
            Observable.error(Throwable("Something went wrong")
         }
      }
  } 
}
```

The PERSON_LOG_TAG gives "expected the BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT error". Any idea how to fix it? This is usually solved by making an outside JSON class like PersonResponse and that has a list of the real class. But I don't know how to do it with a list inside another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API created by conventions than `persons/{personId}` should return Person object instead of list of Persons. So I assume you should replace

```
@GET("persons/{personId}")
fun getPerson(@Path("personId") id: Int): Observable<List<Person>>
```

to

```
@GET("persons/{personId}")
fun getPerson(@Path("personId") id: Int): Observable<Person>
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to remove that since I was pulling from a list before, thanks.